# Visual Studio Code does not Debug Extension to simulate

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I start my simple snippet extension and when I debug the VSCode created a folder `./vsce` with a configuration file automatically.

When I run **F5** in my extension folder, I see this message below.
But VSCode created the file with the configuration, how can I fix this?

`Please set up the launch configuration for your application.`

[image: Visual Studio Code]

Comment: Rafael, even though you answered your own question, it's not in the format that is required for Stackoverflow, which is a Q&A site. So you should actually insert a real question in your text above.

Answer (score 0):

This file is wrong `.vscode/launch.json`, is necessary add to git this folder, change to this:

```
// A launch configuration that compiles the extension and then opens it inside a new window
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}" ]
        }
    ]
}
```